# SQL: Extracting data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am looking to show in ascending order the NameOfMovie that occur most often from the MoviePlaylist where the Playlist Genre_Name = TV Shows or 90’s movie.

The three tables are setup as follows:

```
   Movie => MovieID, NameOfMovie
   PlaylistMovie => MovieID, PlaylistID
   Playlist => PlaylistID, Genre_Name
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
Select movie.MovieId, movie.NameOfMovie, playlisttrack.PlaylistId
From playlisttrack
Inner Join movie on movie.MovieId = playlistMovie.MovieId
Inner Join playlist on playlistMovie.playlistId = playlist.playlistId
where playlistMovie.PlaylistId = 'TV Shows' or playlistMovie.PlaylistId = '90s Movie'
group by Movie.Name;
```

Comment: 1). "Does not work" doesn't explain *anything*.  2). Please include some *sample* data and the results you expect : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
select track.Name, 
       count(*) track_count
  from playlisttrack
 inner Join track on track.TrackId = playlisttrack.TrackId
 inner Join playlist on playlisttrack.playlistId = playlist.playlistId
where playlisttrack.PlaylistId = 3 or playlisttrack.PlaylistId = 5
group by track.Name
order by 2 desc;
```